# Probability problem involving passenger at the station waiting for transportation which come with time difference

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Problem is like this.

> Trasnport A comes every T1 minutes, transport B every T2 minutes. They
>   may or may not be synchronized. u and v points beloging to T1 and T2 show when the passenger arrived to the station and also how long he/she should wait for the next transport of T1 or T2. We assume that u and v points are equally possible in T1 and T2. Should find the probability of the passenger coming to the station
>   waiting no longer than 0 < t < min(T1,T2).

To be honest I don't know even where to start. I just can graphically describe things.

Thanks for your time and support!

Comment: Do you assume $T_i$ are independent exponential RVs? Or? What is the waiting time distribution here?

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 It doesn't sound to me like $T_i$ are rRV's at all.  I think they are numbers.  Transport A arrive every $35$ minutes for example.  It's the passenger's arrival time that is random.

Comment: @saulspatz indeed but how do we reconcile that with the end goal to “find the probability of the passenger coming to the station waiting no longer than” $T>t$ where $T=\min\{T_1,T_2\}$? Since this is so amenable to exponential distributions, I couldn’t resist inquiring.

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 Yes, I have no idea how to solve the problem if it means what I think it means.  Indeed if transport A arrives every hour on the hour, and transport B arrives at ten minutes after the hour, then $P(W<t) = (t+\min\{t,10\})/60,$  but if transport B arrives at $20$ minutes after the hour ... And that's with $T_1=T_2=60.$  What if $T_1,T_2$ are relatively prime integers?  What if they're real numbers?  I haven't a clue.

Comment: Yes T1 and T2 are independent @LoveTooNap29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you walk into a station at a random time and there is just one mode of transport which operates every $T$ minutes, it is clear that the probability for the waiting time $t$ is constant in that interval, and hence given by the formula $P(t) = 1/T$ for $0 < t < T$ and zero otherwise.

Here we have a case where there are two modes of transport, operating with different regular intervals $T(1)$ and $T(2)$. Again you walk into the station at a random time. In my approach of the problem, I found it convenient make a sketch of the probability space for the waiting times of the two modes of transport. In this case the probability space is a rectangular figure, with sides of length $T(1)$ and $T(2)$.

We can easily establish that the probability associated with a minimum waiting time $t$ corresponds to two intervals in the figure, of length $T(1)-t$ and $T(2)-t$ respectively. All one has to do now is to take the sum of these two contributions and normalize to unity, by dividing by the surface area of the rectangle. This way we find:

$$P(t) = [T(1) + T(2) - 2t]/[T(1)*T(2)]$$ for $0 < t < min(T(1),T(2))$ and zero otherwise.